# PopSQL connect, test and save buttons not doing anything

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, popsql

I'm a beginner with mySQL and database management systems in general. The connect, Test and Save buttons don't seem to work whenever I try to connect. It's worth mentioning that the buttons aren't grayed out, it just doesn't do anything, and it also works just fine on the web version of PopSQL, except, the switch isn't ticked for Direct Connection when I save it from the web version.

Since I'm a beginner, I'm not sure what could be the problem or where to ask this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What software are you using to connect to Postgresql?
Take a picture and upload it here!